# Is there a day with time slot selector jquery plugin/picker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, timepicker, picker

I need to implement a form for the doctors who register with their name and available days with time.(ie, Mon - 10.00am to 12.30pm , Tue - 9.00am to 1.00pm like that.) . For this i have a field for choosing the day and time,is there any picker available ? i have tried many daytime picker,weekline picker etc . None of them meet the exact requirement . If this is available that would be great,else i need to manually implement :/  ?

Thank You

Comment: Why not use a select box? Your specific time periods would not be catered by generic tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap "datetimepicker". If you want from and to time interval then use like

```
$('#from-datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().hours(0).minutes(0),
    allowInputToggle : true,
    format : 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    showClose: true,
    showClear: true,
    showTodayButton: true,
    useStrict: true,
    toolbarPlacement: "top"
});

$('#to-datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: moment().hours(23).minutes(59),
    allowInputToggle : true,
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
    sideBySide: true,
    showClose: true,
    showClear: true,
    showTodayButton: true,
    toolbarPlacement: "top"
});
```